# What's the correct way to self-host a Deno library?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, deno

I've set up an apache2 server and have located my library at `http://example.com/lib/deno/test@1.0.0/` and then created a 301 redirect from `http://example.com/lib/deno/test/` to the former. In VS Code (using deno plugin) I noticed that when I import something like `https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts` I get a warning message:

```
Implicitly using latest version (0.140.0) for https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts deno(deno-warn)
```

Following the url it re-directs to `https://deno.land/std@1.140.0/http/server.ts`

However when I import my own `http://example.com/lib/deno/test/mod.ts` I do not get a similar message. Is this warning somehow hard coded to only work with deno.land or am I not hosting things correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deno provides an implementation of the [Language Server Protocol](https://deno.land/manual@v1.22.0/language_server/overview). To integrate tightly with all of its capabilities in regard to module discovery, autocomplete, etc. you will need to implement a *module registry*, which is described here:

https://deno.land/manual@v1.22.0/language_server/imports

Here are the basics of what is required, but you'll need to understand the details of the API endpoints, schema, etc. to succeed in your implementation.

> ### Registry support for import completions
>
> In order to support having a registry be discoverable by the Deno language server, the registry needs to provide a few things:
>
> - A schema definition file. This file needs to be located at `/.well-known/deno-import-intellisense.json`. This file provides the configuration needed to allow the Deno language server query the registry and construct import specifiers.
> - A series of API endpoints that provide the values to be provided to the user to complete an import specifier.

Answer (score 1):

The "Implicitly using latest version" message is actually transmitted by the deno.land server as an HTTP response header. To serve a similar warning message from your own server, you will need to add a similar response header to your HTTP 302 redirect responses. You can supply any message to be displayed.

The response header from deno.land can be viewed like so:

```
> curl -XGET -I https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts
HTTP/2 302 
location: /std@0.140.0/http/server.ts
x-deno-warning: Implicitly using latest version (0.140.0) for https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts
```

How you attach this header to your redirects will depend on your web server.

For reference, you can view the relevant deno.land/x source on Github: https://github.com/denoland/dotland/blob/cd43f5f4a8d2dcb8982f96c0265dde8c8d69a304/routes/x/module.tsx#L638-L645